# How can I use "abroad"?

Tags: word-usage

hello I am not native english speaker  then I saw this  word in a dictionary  **abroad**
in spanish **en el extrangero**

a example that I could do is this:

> I a in abroad
>
> they are in abroad

if this word is more commmon in USA? i listen somtimes more this "in another countires" and not abroad a lot.

my exaple are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this word common in the USA? I sometimes hear "in another country".

The word "abroad" is fairly common. A fluent English speaker would certainly know it.

Checking a couple of word frequency lists, it appears the word "country" is around #200, and the word "abroad" around #2000.

> Are my examples correct?

Not exactly, no.

The most usual ways to say "abroad" are "traveled abroad", "studied abroad", "went abroad".  Here are examples from the deepl.com translation page:

> **en el extranjero** (adv.)
>
> - I want to study abroad. *Quiero estudiar en el extranjero.*
> - My brother returned home after two years abroad. *Mi hermano volvió a casa después de dos años en el extranjero.*
> - I must grasp the opportunity to study abroad. *Debo aprovechar la oportunidad de estudiar en el extranjero.*
>
> **fuera** (adv.)
>
> - I want to travel abroad and learn about other cultures. *Quiero viajar fuera y aprender sobre otras culturas.*

Comment: oh Thank you @Sam your example are great and helpful